# SQL Server : select a substring from every row in a table

Tags: sql-server, iteration

I have a table in a database (that I am not allowed to modify) that is setup in the following manner:

```
ID  Value                                                                 Column x...
0   Apple: GDGolden Delicious, Date Picked: 5/5/2012, Color: Yellow
1   Apple: GSGranny Smith, Date Picked: 3/24/2010, Color: Green
2   Apple: RDRed Delicious, Date Picked: 1/15/2012, Color: Red
3   Random Data, Apple: BRBrayburn, Date Picked: 2/15/2012, Color: Mixed
```

`ID` is an `INT` and `Value` is a `VarChar`, delimited by commas between data.

For every row in the table, I need to pull out a substring of what is listed, in this case, the abbreviation for each fruit variety (i.e. GD, GS, RD, BR) and place it into a temporary table that contains all of the other columns from that table, along with the substring but no other data from the `Value` column. Each substring abbreviation in the table is exactly two characters, although as you see on the last row, it does not always appear at the beginning of the column.

In my reading, it sounds like I'd have to use a cursor to do this -- but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible. Is there anyway to accomplish this without using a cursor, through a case statement or subquery perhaps?

The end result would look like this:

```
ID  Value  Column x  Column y...
0   GD     
1   GS     
2   RD     
3   BR
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will the structure of the record always be `Apple: XX`?

Comment: For simplicity purposes, we'll say yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the event, your record does not say `Apple:`, you can look for the first `:`:

```
select id, 
  substring(value, charindex(':', value, 1) + 2, 2) value
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0e72/13)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX('Apple: ',value)+7, 2)
    FROM YourTable
```